# Asymptotic behavior of max of chi-squared distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose $X_{\max}$ is the maximum in a sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ where each $X_i\sim\chi^2_k$ is an i.i.d. chi-squared random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom.

Since chi squared distribution has an exponential tail, for some fixed number of degrees of freedom $k$ we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_{\max}}{\ln n}=c$ almost surely, with $c$ being a constant (see Example 3.5.6 on page 176 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=BXOI2pICfJUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Modelling%20Extremal%20Events%20for%20Insurance%20and%20Finance#v=onepage&q=Modelling%20Extremal%20Events%20for%20Insurance%20and%20Finance&f=false)).  A weaker convergence in probability claim can be made using the convergence of the distribution of appropriately centered $X_{\max}$ to Gumbel (see summary in Table 3.4.4 on page 156 of the [same reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=BXOI2pICfJUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Modelling%20Extremal%20Events%20for%20Insurance%20and%20Finance#v=onepage&q=Modelling%20Extremal%20Events%20for%20Insurance%20and%20Finance&f=false)).

However, what happens if both the number of degrees of freedom $k$ also increases, though at a rate that is slower than the increase in the number of random variables in the sequence $n$?  For example, let $n=k^2$ (in general, my $n=\omega(k)$).  Is there a result similar to the above, with $k\rightarrow\infty$ (which implies that $n\rightarrow\infty$)?

Does convergence of the distribution of $X_{\max}$ to Gumbel even apply with centering in the above-referenced Table 3.4.4 under these conditions? (the norming constant $d_n$ is negative when $n=k^2$ is substituted, so I think there is trouble here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure this must be written somewhere but since I don't know a reference, let me sketch the computation. I hope there is no error in computation below.

As I commented in your related post, what you are dealing with is the sum of $t=k/2$ exponentials (let's assume $k$ is even, the case of $k$ odd is not really that different). I will also assume that $\log n<<t$ since this seems to be the 
regime you care about; the adaptation to the other cases I leave to you, I did not check the details.

Thus, $X_1=\sum_{i=1}^t E_i$, with $E_i$ exponential variables. Thus, for $w<1$, 
$P(X_1>t+w\sqrt{t})$ is of order $1$ while for $w>1$ but $w<<\sqrt{t}$, as long as $t\to\infty$, you have Gaussian tails:
$$P(X_1>t+w\sqrt{t})\sim c_1 e^{-c_2 w^2}/g(t)\,,$$
for some function $g(t)$ that is essentially of polynomial growth and which I have not computed - it is $\sqrt{t}$ for moderately large $w$'s but later it may change.
(For this you need to appeal to known results on precise moderate deviations for sums of independent variables, e.g. as in Petrov's book on sums of independent random variables; there is a big difference in your original question between $t$ fixed and $t$ growing in $n$ in that the tail estimate change from Gaussian to exponential, and this affects the scaling.).
When $w$ becomes of order $\sqrt{t}$ or larger, then you get a different tail estimate, 
but I do not discuss this case in details - basically you get into large deviations regime and beyond.

Now, just follow the derivation of the law of the max: you get, for the range you care about,
$$P(X_{\max}<t+z)\sim (1-c_1e^{-c_2 (z/\sqrt{t})^2}/g(t))^n\sim
e^{-c_1n e^{-c_2 (z/\sqrt{t})^2}/g(t)}.$$
Now you choose $z=c_2'\sqrt{t\log n}-c_3\log g(t)\sqrt{t/\log n}+z'\sqrt{t/\log n}$. Then,
with appropriate choice of constants,
$$P(X_\max<t+z)\sim e^{-c_1e^{-c_4 z'}}\,,$$
which is Gumbel (note that the centering is $t+c_2'\sqrt{t\log n}-c_3 (\log g(t))\sqrt{t/\log n}$).
For this to work, I used that $\log n<<t$, so that $z/\sqrt{t}<<\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!  I don't see any problems with the mathematics in your derivation, though I need to locate Petrov's book and look up the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, and function $g(t)$ (also, where do $c'_2$ and $z'$ come from?).  It is fascinating how different the centering term is from the case when $k$ is constant. Looks like $\frac{X_{\max}-t}{\sqrt{t\log n}}\rightarrow c$ in probability (is that correct?) -- I wonder if that can be strengthened to "almost surely" (a topic for a different discussion).

Comment: Correct, in the range indicated. Yes, you can strengthen to a.s. - the tail estimates are good enough for that. I also did not look up the precise asymptotics in the literature and therefore am not sure what is $g(t)$ in the whole range - for moderately small $w$ it will be $\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help! I have another question: you say "now you choose $z=c_2'\sqrt{t\log n}-c_3\log g(t)\sqrt{t/\log n}+z'\sqrt{t/\log n}$". I think what you are doing is finding $z=f(t,n,g(n),z')$ which allows $P(X_{\max}<t+z)$ to be expressed as Gumbel $e^{-c_1 e^{-c_4 z'}}$. However, when I try to plug in your expression for $z$, it doesn't work: there leftover terms involving $g(t)$, which doesn't cancel out.  The expression I get by solving $ne^{-c_2(x/\sqrt{t})^2}/g(t)=e^{-c_4z'}$ is $z=\sqrt{t(\log(n)-\log(g(n))+c_4z')/g(n)}$. Could you please clarify what step I am missing?

Comment: just expand and use taylor. With my choice, $z/\sqrt(t)$ equals $c_2'\sqrt{\log n}-c_3\log g(t)/\sqrt{\log n}+z'/\sqrt{\log n}$. When squaring, and taking into account that $g(t)$ is essentially a power of $t$ (maybe this is what you did not use?) you get $C_1 \log n-C_2\log g(t)+C_3z'+o(1)$. It is true that the $C_1$ and $C_2$ terms are of the same order here, if $t$ is a power of $n$. BTW, it is $g(t)$, not really $g(n)$, but of course $n$ and $t$ are related in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  In my previous comment, I meant $g(t)$: $g(n)$ was a typo.  I re-did my expansion of the square and see now that everything reconciles.  The confusing term was $\frac{c_3^2\log^2(g(t))}{\log(n)}$, but as you point out, $g(t)$ is a power of $t$, and, in turn, $t$ (in my scenario) is a power of $n$, so the log in the denominator cancels out one of the logs in the numerator.

Comment: I also located a copy of Petrov's "Sums of Independent Random Variables" but I can't find the result you use on the tail of sum of exponentials $P(X_1>t+w\sqrt{t})\sim c_1 e^{-c_2 w^2}/g(t)$. While I have a pretty good grasp at the probability theory (graduate research in engineering and accompanying coursework), that book is pretty dense. Is there another reference that you can point me to? Intuitively, the law you cite makes sense to me, but I just want to find out where it comes from. If you want, I can write this comment as a separate question (the answer may be useful to others).

Comment: I am travelling and have no access to the book in the next few days. It should be under the header ``probability of large deviations for variables satisfying Cramer's conditions''. Another good source is Nagaev's review article in Annals of Probability has in its very beginning the kind of result you need: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.aop/1176994938

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the relevant part in Petrov's book. I think eq (2.1) in Chapter VIII, theorem 1, provides the asymptotic distribution of large deviation from the mean of chi-squared random variable, however, I still can't figure where $g(t)\approx\sqrt{t}$ comes from. I am guessing it's from the term $\exp\left\{\frac{w^3}{\sqrt{t}}\lambda(w/\sqrt{n})\right\}$ however, I cannot find anything about Cramer series $\lambda(t)$ other than that's "a power series with coefficients depending on the cumulants" (as states later in the theorem 2.1). But how does $g(t)\approx\sqrt{t}$ arise?

Comment: I also posted a [related question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143560/behavior-of-the-average-of-the-exponents-of-chi-squared-random-variables-normali) along the similar line of inquiry... any hints/ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: First, the term $1/\sqrt{t}$ comes from the normal distribution $(1-\Phi(t))$). So the question is whether the rest converges to a constant or not. The function $\lambda$ can be computed, but it is not important: it is a nice analytical function, so can be expanded in power series at the origin (recall that $w<<\sqrt{t}$). So if you are in the regime where $w$ is much smaller than a polynomial in $t$ (which is your case), this whole term converges to $1$. All this will change of course if you start taking $log n$ which is proportional to a fractional power of $k$ in your original question.

Comment: Aha! I've known that $1-\Phi(t)\sim \frac{2\pi} e^{-t^2/2}$ but I didn't know that the [error function can be asymptotically expanded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion) to give the additional $1/\sqrt{t}$ factor.  It all makes sense now!  Thank you for your help and patience with me!

Comment: Looking at this again, shouldn't the expression for $g(t)=w$?  At large $x$, $1-\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}x}e^{-x^2/2}$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function#Bounds)), and argument in the answer is $w$. Then $P(X_1>t+w\sqrt{t})\sim c_1e^{-c_2w^2}/w$, which results, I think, in expression for $z$ involving the square root of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (there is an approximation $W(x)\approx \log(x)-\log\log(x)$ for large $x$ so we may still end up with Gumbel.)  Or am I missing a step and $g(t)=\sqrt{t}$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: No. For $w=1$, $P(X_1>t+\sqrt{t})\sim 1/\sqrt{t}$, unlike what you wrote (this is just the local CLT). This discussion has gone however beyond reasonable for MO, I suggest you contact me by email if things still do not work out for you after you think about them.